# How clean Ganache data?

Tags: truffle, ganache

I'm starting Ganache v7 by this command like:

```
ganache -p 7545 -i 7777 --wallet.deterministic --database.dbPath ~/myPathGanache/
```

I've migrated some contracts, test them and now I intend to start my local Ganache blockchain from zero. So, I stopped Ganache and deleted all files under `~/myPathGanache/` and then started Ganache again.

However, when I connect to it using `truffle console --network myGanacheNetworkName` and run the command `networks` before I run the project's migrations, my old contracts are still there.

What do I need to do in order to "clean" my Ganache data?

Regards,

Comment: Did you try truffle migrate --reset

Comment: Thanks, @AbhishekSinha. Your suggestion solved the case ;)